# Can't pass data from activity to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I am trying to pass these data from my activity to my receiver when user click a song.

MyActivity

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Other codes
                  try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockScreenReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pos", newPosition2).putExtra("songlist", mySongs).putExtra("lockSound", "lock");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Intent error");
                }
}
```

And this is what I wrote in my receiver class

Receiver

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
    int position = b.getInt("pos", 0);

    Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, u);

    lockMusic = b.getString("lockSound");


    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    {
        if(lockMusic!=null){
        mp.start();
        }
    }
 }
```

my app crashes when I click my song.

Not sure if this is the right error message:

```
 11-12 21:30:40.562  24747-24747/com.piersonleo.lockscreensound E/SecondScreen﹕ Intent error
```

Comment: Please, add error messages to your question too, so it is easier to answer.

Comment: I added it but I don't know if it;s correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define your receiver in your manifest.xml

```
   <receiver android:name="com.xxx.xxx.LockScreenReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Second, sendBroadcast with data like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.xxx.xxx.xxxx");
intent.putExtra("pos", newPosition2).putExtra("songlist",   mySongs).putExtra("lockSound", "lock");
sendBroadcast(i);
```